# "Failed - network Error" while downloading large size of data as image using html2canvas.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, export, html2canvas

I have one function which convert data into image and download it. It works fine when data is small, but when data is large then I am getting "Failed - network Error". How to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
function genImageFile() {
    html2canvas($('.pvtRendererArea')[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test file.png');
        } else {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = $('#title').text() + '.png';
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.click();
        }
    });
};
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution in this case?