# Why do I keep getting a failed download error?

Tags: java, c#, html

`My download button is working but I always get the Failed- Network Error message below the download.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container-fluid row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="downloadBtn">
        <i class="bi bi-download"></i> Download as PDF
    </button>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.2.2/html2canvas.min.js">.            </script>

<script>function screenshotAndDownload() {
    const form = document.querySelector('.container-fluid.row');
    html2canvas(form).then((canvas) => {
        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/pdf');
        downloadBase64File('image/pdf', imageData, 'child_information');
    });
}


function downloadBase64File(contentType, base64Data, fileName) {
    const linkSource = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName + ".pdf";
    downloadLink.click();
}


document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Downloading");
    screenshotAndDownload();
});</script>
```

I have tried changing to jpg but still does not work. Script tags are already placed on their respective controllers. `

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Ryan Only this

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: I get [Network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314215/failed-network-error-while-downloading-large-size-of-data-as-image-using-htm) while loading in Chrome. It is a popular problem, unfortunately not sure what the reason of it.

Comment: How is your question related to C# and Java? Note that Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert the image to a pdf first because html2canvas only converts to png or jpeg here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="downloadBtn">
            <i class="bi bi-download"></i> Download as PDF
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF  //insert jsPDF into script

    function downloadBase64File(contentType, base64Data, fileName) {
        const linkSource = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`;
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = fileName + ".pdf";
        downloadLink.click();
    }
            
    function screenshotAndDownload() {
        const form = document.querySelector('.container-fluid.row');
        html2canvas(form).then((canvas) => {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');            // Create a new jsPDF instance
            const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  // Convert the canvas to an image data URL
            pdf.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297);   // Add the image to the PDF
            pdf.save('child_information.pdf');                 // Save the PDF with the specified file name
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("Downloading");
        screenshotAndDownload();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally worked but I have to edit my code. The code you provided only captured the <h1> from my page and not the entire page